# Need Date validation in bootstrap for the formate "DD/Mon/YYYY"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, date

My date formate is "DD/Mon/YYYY". I am changing the date chosen from date picker to this formate. On form submit I need to validate the date. I tried

```
dob : {
            container : 'popover',
            validators : {
                notEmpty : {
                    message : 'DOB cannot be empty'
                },
                date: {
                    format: 'DD/Mon/YYYY',
                    separator:'/',
                    message: 'The value is not a valid date'
                }
            }
        }
```

But its not working. Can anyone tell me what is the exact format to be specified?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using the same way to format but try this out :

```
this.format = DPGlobal.parseFormat(options.format||this.element.data('date-format')||'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

So Try `dd/mm/yyyy` instead of `DD/Mon/YYYY`

Because the datepicker uses this format :

```
for (var i=0, cnt = format.parts.length; i < cnt; i++) {
                val = parseInt(parts[i], 10)||1;
                switch(format.parts[i]) {
                    case 'dd':
                    case 'd':
                        day = val;
                        date.setDate(val);
                        break;
                    case 'mm':
                    case 'm':
                        month = val - 1;
                        date.setMonth(val - 1);
                        break;
                    case 'yy':
                        year = 2000 + val;
                        date.setFullYear(2000 + val);
                        break;
                    case 'yyyy':
                        year = val;
                        date.setFullYear(val);
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: I want the date look like this format "02/Jun/1993". I have tried what u said early. It was not working as i need.